# How to access the version information within Nextflow's manifest scope

Tags: nextflow

Say I have a manifest scope defined like so

```
manifest {
    version = '1.2.3'
}
```

If I try to access the version component of that scope in a process, like this:

```
process TEST {
    script:
        """
        somescript ${manifest.version}
        """
}
```

Then I get an error saying:
 `No such variable: manifest`

**Is it possible to access the variables within the manifest scope in Nextflow, and, if so, what is the proper syntax.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entries in the [manifest scope](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/config.html#scope-manifest) can be accessed using the [`workflow`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/metadata.html) object. To get the pipeline version number from the manifest (assuming it has been set), use: `workflow.manifest.version`. Your test process might then look like:

```
process test {
    
    """
    echo "${workflow.manifest.version}"
    """
}
```